# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 113: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, sql, database

I have a question about Python in combination with MySqldb.
I need to get the specific URLs of each client out of an SQL database. Everything works as it should be the moment I try to access the data in a specific table I get a **UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 113: character maps to**  error and I can't seem to fix it.

class sql:

```
def __init__(self, host, user, password, database): 
    self.host = host 
    self.user = user 
    self.password = password
    self.database = database
    self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(host, user, password, database)
    self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
    self.client_list = []
    self.client_id_list = []
    self.client_url_dict = {}

def check_if_connected(self): 
    if (self.conn): 
        print("Connectie met {} is succesvol.".format(self.database))
    else: 
        print("Connectie met {} is gefaald.".format(database))

def preperations(self): 
    self.cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES;")
    clients = self.cursor.fetchall()
    for client_not_stripped in clients: 
        client = str(client_not_stripped).strip("()',")
        self.client_id_list.append(str(client).strip("urls_of_client"))
        self.client_list.append(client)
    print("{} heeft {} clienten in de database.".format(self.database, len(self.client_list)))
    for client_id in self.client_id_list: 
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM urls_of_client_{}".format(client_id))
        urls = self.cursor.fetchall()
```